# Running php via command line

Tags: php, command-line

I am trying to run php script via command line on ubuntu.
I creted test.php with

```
<?php
   
    echo "test";

?>
```

When I run this script with

```
php test.php
```

i get this output

```
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskAvail ::= { dskEntry 7 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskTotal ::= { dskEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskMinPercent ::= { dskEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskMinimum ::= { dskEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskDevice ::= { dskEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskPath ::= { dskEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: dskIndex ::= { dskEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-DISKIO-MIB: diskIOTable ::= { ucdDiskIOMIB 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLoggingGroup ::= { nsConfigGroups 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsDebugGroup ::= { nsConfigGroups 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrErrMessage ::= { snmperrs 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrErrorFlag ::= { snmperrs 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrNames ::= { snmperrs 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: snmperrIndex ::= { snmperrs 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsTransactionTable ::= { nsTransactions 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogStatus ::= { nsLoggingEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogMaxLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogType ::= { nsLoggingEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogToken ::= { nsLoggingEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsLogLevel ::= { nsLoggingEntry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendResult ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutNumLines ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutputFull ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutput1Line ::= { nsExtendOutput1Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendOutLine ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB: nsExtendLineIndex ::= { nsExtendOutput2Entry 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyStart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 1 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyShutdown ::= { netSnmpNotifications 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB: nsNotifyRestart ::= { netSnmpNotifications 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrMessage ::= { laEntry 101 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laErrorFlag ::= { laEntry 100 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadFloat ::= { laEntry 6 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoadInt ::= { laEntry 5 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laConfig ::= { laEntry 4 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laLoad ::= { laEntry 3 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laNames ::= { laEntry 2 }
Cannot adopt OID in UCD-SNMP-MIB: laIndex ::= { laEntry 1 }
test
```

Dou you know what this means? Why I am getting this error and how can i get rid of this output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try running either this

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-snmp
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install snmp
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I am on Debian Jessie and `sudo apt-get install snmp` did the trick, I upgraded using dotdeb.

Comment: just disable the module using `sudo phpdismod snmp`